# Why is this ISO string improperly converted to New York time in moment timezone?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have an ISO date string `2007-08-17T04:00:00.000Z` that I would like to convert from its given UTC time to the time in New York. I am using the [Moment Timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/).

This is the expected behavior:

`console.log(moment('2008-09-22T04:00:00.000Z').tz('America/New_York').format()); // 2008-09-22T00:00:00-04:00`

However the observed behavior is the following:

`console.log(moment('2008-09-22T04:00:00.000Z').tz('America/New_York').format()); // 2008-09-21T23:00:00-05:00`

It appears that Moment Timezone is incorrectly labeling August in New York as EST (UTC-5) when it is correctly EDT (UTC-4).

Is my expected behavior incorrect? Is this a known issue with Moment Timezone? I have not seen any reference to an error of this sort elsewhere.

Comment: Are you using the "all years" database? Also, historical time zones may be different in moment.js when compared to ECMAScript.

Comment: Your first question did it. I was using the 2010-2020 data version. Thank you!